# Why does my model of a wind turbine show high RPM with low power output?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, turbines, wind-power

I am designing a wind turbine to generate 1300 W.

I modeled the output voltage of an AC generator using the following specifics:

- Number coil turns = 300.
- Copper wire gauge = 1.02 mm.
- Knowing the density of copper, I calculated the weight of the coil to be 4.39 kg.
- Magnetic field strength = 1.24 T. ([here are the specs for the magnet](http://www.arnoldmagnetics.com/Portals/0/Files/Catalogs%20and%20Lit/Neo/151021/N38AH%20-%20151021.pdf?ver=2015-12-07-103811-373))
- Area = 1 m<sup>2</sup>.
- Rotational speed = 45 RPM.

I plugged these numbers into the output voltage equation:

$$\epsilon = NBA\omega\sin(\omega t)$$

to get a value of 1753 V. I am assuming that my generator will generate at least the 0.74 A to output a power of 1300 W.

Then, I modeled my turbine. I used the equation:

$$P_T = \frac{1}{2}\rho A v^3 C_p$$

to calculate rotor power. I assumed:

- My turbine would be 30% efficient.
- The wind velocity would be 10 m/s.
- The area swept by blades would be 2.63 m<sup>2</sup>.
- The density of air would be 1.25.

After plugging these values in, I get a power yield of 493 W. However, I find that the rotor speed is well above 45 RPM. This equation gives the tip speed ratio of the turbine:

$$\lambda = \frac{wr}{v}$$

Knowing that the optimum tip speed ratio of a three-blade turbine is 4.2, radius of the rotor blade is 0.915 m, and velocity of air is 10 m/s, that angular velocity would be 45.9 rad/s or 440 RPM.

How can I get 1300 W from this turbine when the theoretical yield from power of the rotor is only 493 W, even though my rotor should turn at the correct RPM for the generator to produce 1300 W?

Comment: `Converting this to rpm would yield 440 rpm`  That's quite fast for a wind turbine.  It will probably shake itself to pieces.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers what am I doing wrong?

Comment: the kinetic energy of wind gives a power yield of 1643.89W (without multiplying Cp). However, I am assuming my turbine will be 30% efficient; thus, I am getting a rotor power of 493W. My turbine has a very small swept area, so is my assumption that my efficiency of the turbine be 30% false?? I know the power coefficient is related to tip speed ratio and pitch, but will the small area also have an effect?

Comment: @user510 What's the source of energy for a wind turbine and how do you capture it? If the rotor power you calculated is too low, what design value(s) do you have the greatest ability to control and how do you change those values to capture more of the wind's energy?

Comment: It sounds like you are working backwards, you need to first design a turbine which will generate the power you need and then design a generator to suit that power requirement. The dimensions of a generator give you its maximum capacity they don't guarantee that it will generate that amount of power. You may also want to look at existing generators specs for a reality check.

Comment: You do see that 1800 V are really too much, you should aim for for a quarter or fifth of that. You won't be able to use the power at all if you keep this voltage, except if you get a transformer to lower it. But this is nonsense as you could just redesign your generator. A better idea for your setup could be an asynchronous generator (has no magnets), as it will be less complicated to use, it has tolerances for the rpm-s and a well designed system could work by directly connecting it to the mains (it needs mains or capacitors for the magnetization current).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you really designed a 1300 W wind turbine. You *assumed* your generator would be able to produce the necessary current but to be able to produce 1300 W you have to build a wind turbine big enough, given its efficiency.

At $C_p=0.3$ and $v=10\ \mathrm{m/s}$, you simply need an area of:
$$A=\frac{2P_T}{C_pv^3\rho}=7.07\ \mathrm{m^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow R=1.5\ \mathrm{m}$$

Moreover, you say $\lambda=4.2$ is optimal for a three-blade turbine, but it actually depends on the blade profile, which is optimized for a given "design tip speed ratio". For more information about this, see chapter 3.7 of "Burton, *Wind energy handbook*, 2011".

See also "Duquette, *Numerical Implications of Solidity and Blade Number on Rotor Performance of Horizontal-Axis Wind Turbines*, 2003" about influence of blade number on power coefficient.

Comment: so the generator's max power output should match the rotor's max power output?

Comment: No, the generator max power should be a bit higher than the rated output of the rotor, because gusts of wind might exceed the rated wind speed ($v=10m/s$) and make the wind turbine output more than 1300W. But ultimately the whole system won't output more power than the rotor.